# NTFS vs FAT32 Popularity (Dec '15)

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, fat32

Are there any publicly-available data on what file system PC users' home drives are formatted to? I'm only really interested in Windows, but broader stats will likely take into account Windows' market domination, so I'll take what I can get without complaining.

I ask because I want to implement something into a project I'm working on that makes use of NTFS-only features, and I want to know exactly how large a share of the market I would potentially be alienating by omitting FAT32 and ReFS support.

To re-iterate, I'm only looking for the file systems of the *home drives* (eg, the drive containing C:\WINDOWS) of the survey-takers. Valve's hardware survey records seem like a perfect candidate but this is not an aspect they comment on.

Comment: You do realise you can't install modern windows on anything but NTFS, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to look at shares of OS. Windows Vista and above can only be installed on NTFS. [source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926069)

There may be some workarounds to get them to work, but, realistically, nobody would be doing this, especially now.

[OS Market Share](https://www.netmarketshare.com/operating-system-market-share.aspx?qprid=10&qpcustomd=0) (Over 77% of OS's in use are Windows 7+ according to this survey, but look around at others of course).